# Parser for reversed language

Tags: automata

Language $L$ is specyfied by grammar : $(\{S,A,B\},\{c,d\},S,\{S \rightarrow SA, A \rightarrow Bc | \epsilon, B \rightarrow d\})$.

My task is to construct LR(1) parsing table for language $L^R$ (with, as far as I understand, is a reverse of language L). I know very well how to construct LR(1) parsing table, what I request for is that somebody explain to me how to deal with $L^R$ in this case.

Comment: Is there a rule to get rid of the start symbol $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you ask for the meaning of $L^R$.
$$
L^R = \{ w^R \mid w \in L \}
$$
where the word reversal might be defined like
\begin{align}
\epsilon^R &= \epsilon \\
a^R &= a \quad (a \in \Sigma) \\
(a w)^R &= w^R a \quad (a \in \Sigma, w \in L)
\end{align}
The RHS reversed production rules should do the job:
\begin{align}
S &\to A S\\
A &\to cB \mid \epsilon \\
B &\to d
\end{align}

Comment: OK, but how that affect on constructing parsing table process? Does it change the productions some way, or anything else in grammar?

Comment: OK, now I understand. So I change the productions the way you made it and everything else stays the same. Thanks a lot, that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Like this the grammar for $L$ seems to produce words $w = S(dc)^*$ and the modified grammar words $w = (cd)^*S$. That is why I wonder how to replace $S$ with some terminal symbol.